Tabs Studio alternative for Visual Studio shortcut to move or arrange tab order
I want to move my tab side to side using keyboard. In VSCode the shortcut is CTRL + SHIFT + PgDn or CTRL + SHIFT + PgUp, command name is workbench.action.moveEditorRightInGroup, but there is no similar command in VS 2022. However this can be achieve by installing Tabs Studio, it's working good but a bit laggy when animation is disabled also the licence cost $49/year and it's too much for me.
Im looking for alternative or work around for this because I working with a lot of tabs.


Shortcuts are defined by default (Ctrl+PgDn / PgUp), the only thing is that it is shadowed by Edit.ViewBottom and Edit.ViewTop. You need to remove or redefine these shortcuts from Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard
Then Ctrl+PgDn/PgUp will allow you to navigate between tabs just like in VS Code.
You can also use Previous document window commands/ (Ctrl+Shift+F6) shortcuts do about the same thing.
For more information,please read doc:global shortcuts
Update
After some researching, it seems that moving tabs side to side using keyboard is not supported in visual studio shortcuts.
Here is a  similar feature request submitted by other user :
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/keyboard-shortcut-for-moving-tabs/1337230
I suggest you can  also submit a new feature request from Visual Studio Forum due to the old one is lack activity.

Window.NextTab and Window.PreviousTab are for navigate or switch to left/right tab. What I ask is what shortcut or command to move or arrange the tab. For example:
[ Tab1.cs | Tab2.cs | Tab3.cs ]
Currently Tab1.cs is on focus and then I press Ctrl+Shit+PgDn, the result should be
[ Tab2.cs | Tab1.cs | Tab3.cs ]

Sorry for misunderstanding your question. It seems it's a new feature not supported in visual studio. Updated  this answer.
